# Will missing an interview for a US visa keep me from getting a UK visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

I graduated from a US university and came back to India. Immediately thereafter I applied for renewal of my visitor visa to the USA as I was planning a trip to UK and thought I would spend a couple of days visiting New York.

I applied under the interview waiver program. However the visa officer issued me a 221(g) form asking me to come for a personal interview. At the same time I was offered a job, which I accepted so didn't go for the interview as I postponed travelling to the USA.

Now I want to renew my UK Standard Visitor visa.

Should I mention the above incident in my UK visa application?

Answer (score 3):

Not of itself (to Title question).

A 221(g) form is issued where further information is required before a visa decision (one way or another) can be taken. It is neither a refusal ("No visa for you") nor a rejection ("Try again"). So this does not need to be disclosed.

(However, I probably would, if I were you.)

Comment: Personally I would not reveal it. UK consular officers are notorious for looking for any reason to refuse an applicant. You have not been refused a visa, there is no need to reveal it and they do not have that information. It is not material information & you don't need to volunteer it..